# Indexed DB cleared cant be opened

Tags: indexeddb

I cleared some indexed DB (from chrome dev) .
indexeddb.open() simply does nothing.
There is no error, no succes, also I have try catch and no error is rised.

How to deal with this problem ?
Why I have not 'success' ?

The code I have is exactly the same which can open my other indexeddbs...

th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to the `upgradeneeded` and `blocked` events. If you just cleared it then I expect `upgradeneeded` to fire.